# Remove files from Directory MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**Code**

```
public ActionResult DeleteProduct(int id)
{
     var FindImageFromDb = DB.ImageGalleries.Where(x => x.ProductIdFk == id).ToList();
     DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"Path");
     string[] Filenames = FindImageFromDb.Select(x => x.ImageName.ToString()).ToArray();
     foreach (FileInfo Files in di.GetFiles(Filenames))
     {
         Files.Delete();
     }  
}
```

getting error on compile time . Error while Passing parameter to GetFiles() in Foreach Loop because i am passing string array but it accepts only one row means single item. so how i can delete the specific files any other way to delete that files Thanks

Comment: Do the filename check inside your loop

Comment: As an aside, you don't seem to be checking that a user is authorised to access this function, and any authorised user can effectively delete *all* the files.  Is this correct?

Comment: @Neil you are right but i have check only logged user can access this Action.so that is Right?

Comment: Sure but does that mean any logged in user can delete any files? E.g. I can delete your files if I know the product id .

Comment: @Neil any logged user has its own record i assigned maximum 5 files to a user so a user only can access own files.and you can delete maximum 5 files against any product id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the filename check to inside your loop:

```
var fileNames = FindImageFromDb.Select(x => x.ImageName.ToString()).ToArray();
foreach (var file in di.GetFiles())
{
    if (fileNames.Any(f => f == file.Name))
    {
        file.Delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: that,s good but problem is that it will get All files files from directory that will take time if have 100000 files in my folder then first it will get all files so after that next process will be start.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (FileInfo Files in Filenames)
     {
         di.GetFiles(Files).delete()

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate through the filenames and retrieve FileInfo inside the loop:

```
 foreach (string filename in filenames)
 {
     FileInfo[] fi = di.GetFiles(filename);
     if (fi != null && fi.Length > 0)
     {
         // Consider if you'd like to check that only one file was found
         // This might happen because GetFiles considers its input as a pattern
         // However if you are using full file names (which is most likely the case), that shouldn't be necessary
         fi[0].Delete();
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Lambda -

```
var files = di.GetFiles().Where(x => Filenames.Any(y => y == x.Name));
```